# How to prevent this overflow error?

Tags: numerics

I compiled the following Mathematica code

```
m = 40;
eea = Integrate[(x - y)^(-(α - 1) - 
     1) ((Sum[(z^(s))*(Cos[((b)^(s))*(π)*(y)]), {s, 0, m}]* 
        Sum[((λ)^((d - 2)*k))*(Sin[(λ^k)*(y)]), {k, 1,
           m}]) - (Sum[(z^(s))*(Cos[((b)^(s))*(π)*(0)]), {s, 0, 
          m}]* Sum[((λ)^((d - 2)*
              k))*(Sin[(λ^k)*(0)]), {k, 1, m}])), {y, 0, x}];
sa = D[eea/ Gamma[-(α - 1)], {x, 1}]
```

So that others may avoid the 1 hour computation, the output of `eea` from *Mathematica* 12.0 can be acquired from the following:

```
eea = Uncompress[Uncompress["1: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"]];
```

After an hour i got an output and for the same i gave the following substitution

```
% /. x -> 1 /. λ -> 3 /. d -> 15/10 /. 
   z -> 1/10 /. α -> 2/10 /. b -> 35
```

Then for the resulting output i calculated the numerical value using the code

```
N[%]
```

So for the above numerical compilation i got the following error message

```
General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
General::stop: Further output of General::ovfl will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Could anyone please suggest any answer to solve this issue.

Thank You

Comment: how long does it take to integrate?

Comment: @Nasser about an hour. Even when i set m=30 i got the same overflow error

Comment: `about an hour` in this case, do you not think it is important to warn people about this in your post?

Comment: @vicky since the integration seems to work, albeit slowly, could you add the value of `eea` in your post so people don’t have to run it themselves but can still run the rest of your code to try and help you?

Comment: @Nasser Sorry I forgot..Will do it

Comment: @MarcoB Ya sure will do it

Comment: After putting a fair bit more work into investigating `sa` via numerical means, it's very unstable. The integrand is very oscillatory, and numerical estimates of that derivative fluctuate randomly even with `WorkingPrecision` of 100+. I'm not sure there is a good way to answer this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment unless you're willing to "believe" in an inference I propose.

The first step is to take a look at your function with `m` undefined:

```
m =.;
integrand = (x - y)^(-(α - 1) - 1) ((Sum[(z^(s))*(Cos[((b)^(s))*(π)*(y)]), {s, 0, m}]*
  Sum[((λ)^((d - 2)*k))*(Sin[(λ^k)*(y)]), {k, 1, m}]) - 
  (Sum[(z^(s))*(Cos[((b)^(s))*(π)*(0)]), {s, 0, m}]*
  Sum[((λ)^((d - 2)*k))*(Sin[(λ^k)*(0)]), {k, 1, m}]))
```

[image: Formula of interest]

So we can integrate the individual terms.

```
integral = Integrate[(x - y)^-α z^s Cos[b^s π y] λ^((-2 + d) k) Sin[y λ^k], 
  {y, 0, x}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, α < 1}]
```

[image: integral of an individual term]

An individual term of the derivative you want is

```
derivative = D[integral/Gamma[-(\[Alpha] - 1)], {x, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: derivative of an individual term]

Now set the parameter values that you list and try values of `s` and `k` that give you the overflow error when getting a numerical value for the term (i.e., using `//N`).  Here's one that does that.

```
parms = {x -> 1, λ -> 3, d -> 15/10, z -> 1/10, α -> 2/10, b -> 35};
derivative /. parms /. s -> 22 /. k -> 1 // N
```

[image: overflow error]
[image: overflow error]
[image: overflow error]
[image: Further output suppressed]

That term without `//N` is

[image: exact value of term]

So we see the likely culprit is the $b^s$ term (how appropriate!).  What to do about that?

Consider rewriting one of the hypergeometric functions as

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -(1/4) (3 - bigBs π)^2]
```

We can evaluate this function for values of `bigBs` until we get overflow errors.  We see that the above function approaches zero with larger values of `bigBs`.  So we could set some threshold for values of `bigBs`.  The proposal is to do so in the following manner:

```
threshold = 10^20;
m = 40;
Sum[derivative /. b^s -> Min[b^s, threshold] /. parms, {s, 0, m}, {k, 1, m}] // N
(* -0.30444 *)
```

This takes about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try higher precision:

```
eea /. x -> 1 /. λ -> 3 /. d -> 15/10 /. 
    z -> 1/10 /. α -> 2/10 /. b -> 35.`50 // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {13.6045, -0.08742710084680679010043795135152006816}  *)
```

Comment: +1 Can't beat a short, to-the-point, fast, accurate answer.